# Unable to swap even number of elements in linked-list

Tags: c, data-structures, linked-list

I am writing code to swap elements in linked list pairwise,my code works fine with odd number of element but is not working with even number of elements
Input-1->2->3->4->5->6->7
Output-2->1->4->3->6->5->7

```
 void sort()
 {
     node *ptr=head;
     node *ptr1=head;
     int temp;
     while(ptr->next!=NULL)
     {
         temp=(ptr->next)->info;
         (ptr->next)->info=ptr->info;
         ptr->info=temp;

         //This statement is not working with even number of elements as
         //when it reaches last element it is going beyond the list and 
         //I am unable to rectify how to rectify this problem
         ptr=(ptr->next)->next;
     }
 }
```

Comment: Why is the function called sort? In my opinion it is a confusing name.

Comment: @Vlad -what's in the name?,the beauty lies in logic

Comment: Your reply sounds nicely philosophical, but is kind of ridiculous in the context of programming. Your function names should always describe what the function does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not check whether the current node is equal to NULL. When the number of nodes is even then after this statement

```
ptr=(ptr->next)->next;
```

`ptr` can be equal to NULL and you do not check this.

The function can be written the following way

```
void adjacent_swap()
{
    for ( node *p = head; p!= NULL && p->next != NULL; p = p->next )
    {
        int tmp = p->info;
        p->info = p->next->info;
        p = p->next;
        p->info = tmp;
    }
}
```

Comment: @Newbie786 I have had a typo in the code I showed. Take into account that there shall be && instead of &.:)

Answer (score 1):

I think `while(ptr->next!=NULL)` should be changed to `while (ptr!=NULL && ptr->next!=NULL)`

Answer (score 0):

Reusing your code just adjust this:

```
while(ptr->next!=NULL && ptr->next->next!=null )
```